# type of expression is ambiguous without more context-Swift

Tags: swift

```
 let contactDict: NSDictionary = ["identifier":singleContact.identifier,"firstName":singleContact.firstName, "lastName":singleContact.lastName,"email":singleContact.email,"phone":singleContact.phone,"contactImage":singleContact.contactImage]
```

I am having type of expression is ambiguous without more context error. I tried resolving it by the following expression

```
 let contactDict: NSDictionary: [NSObject: AnyObject]
```

but this is still showing an error that consecutive statements must be separated by ;

Please help me in rectifying this error.

Comment: Thanks it helped. I just had to put the optional ! at each place.

Comment: Can you please help me with one more issue?

Comment: i am unable to link a button with a navigation controller. I do not know how to do it programmatically. Please help

Comment: i have attached my code and screenshot please have a look on that. I will be very thankful to you if you could help me out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38830264/unable-to-link-button-with-a-navigation-controller-in-ios-programmatically?noredirect=1#comment65026599_38830264

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the consecutive statements error because of the two colons...

```
let contactDict: NSDictionary: [NSObject: AnyObject]
```

should be something like...

```
let contacts: [NSObject: AnyObject] = ...
```

or...

```
let contacts: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = ...
```

Notice that when you use the word `Dictionary` or `NSDictionary` that the format doesn't use brackets: `Dictionary<key, value>`. If you're still getting ambiguous error, try creating it with an empty dictionary literal, and then append:

```
var contacts: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = [:]
contacts[key] = value
```

or...

```
var contacts: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = [:]
contacts += [...]
```